# How to select table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am working on a table and I need to apply functions to each row when clicked. I've been trying to apply CSS to the rows, the CSS only applies to the first row on the table. How can I apply CSS to a particular single row when clicked without interfering with the other rows.

My code below

```
$(function() {
    $('#example a').click(function(e) {
        $(this).next('tr').css('background', 'red');
    });
});

<table id="example" class="display">

<tbody>

    <tr id="ajaxinbox">
        <td class="read-message-now">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <a data-id="{{ $msgBox->mid }}" sender="{{ $msgBox->id }}" att-data="{{ $msgBox->att_msg_ref }}">
                    <span class="sender-name center-block notread" id="{{$msgBox->mid}}">
                        <span class="sender-name center-block" id="nameview"> <small class="datestamp read-datestamp"> </small>
                        </span>
                        <span class="message-subject">
                            <span class="notread" id="msgsub{{$msgBox->mid}}"> </span>
                            <span id="readview"></span>
                            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o hasfile"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <label id="hascheck"><input type="checkbox" name="haschecked" id="{{ $msgBox->mid }}"  value="{{ $msgBox->mid }}" class="i-check" autocomplete="off"><span></span></label>
                </li>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr id="ajaxinbox">
        <td class="read-message-now">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <a data-id="{{ $msgBox->mid }}" sender="{{ $msgBox->id }}" att-data="{{ $msgBox->att_msg_ref }}">
                    <span class="sender-name center-block notread" id="{{$msgBox->mid}}">
                        <span class="sender-name center-block" id="nameview"> <small class="datestamp read-datestamp"> </small>
                        </span>
                        <span class="message-subject">
                            <span class="notread" id="msgsub{{$msgBox->mid}}"> </span>
                            <span id="readview"></span>
                            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o hasfile"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <label id="hascheck"><input type="checkbox" name="haschecked" id="{{ $msgBox->mid }}"  value="{{ $msgBox->mid }}" class="i-check" autocomplete="off"><span></span></label>
                </li>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Your list item elements need to be within a `<ol>` or `<ul>`. Also, IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 1):

`.next()` looks at the next element in line - you need to find the `closest` `<tr>` and set that CSS:

```
$('#example a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').css('background', 'red');
});
```

Also - `<li>` elements must live inside a `<ul>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of next() try the closest() function

```
$(function() {
    $('#example a').click(function(e) {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('background', 'red');
    });
});
```

Or try adding the click event directly to the `tr` element if you like

```
$(function() {
    $('#example tr').click(function(e) {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
    });
});
```